# Java Inputstream, NoFly Server

Tags: java, sockets, server, stream, inputstream

I have an inputstream which looks like "true Name true Name true Name ... false" [made of booleans and Strings]. I need to read a single name from the stream until it reaches false. I tried to do that with the deprecated .readLine() method and using a bufferedreader, yet both seem not to handle the task. I keep getting NameNameName string but I need three separate Name strings.

Code

```
private final DataInputStream in;
private final DataOutputStream out;
private final Collection<String> names;

//there is more code above, it's a request handler for a NoFly Server.

private void doRequest(Function<String, Boolean> fn) throws IOException {

    while(in.readBoolean() && !Thread.interrupted()) {
        //here I need to read the name
        names.add(name);
        //dont mind the function
        boolean val = fn.apply(name);
        System.out.println(val + name);
        out.writeChars(name);
        out.writeBoolean(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is consistence sequence of boolean and String separated by " ". You could try:

```
     //input sequence of (boolean, String), (..., ...), ...
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream("true Name true Name true Name false NameNotDisplayedFalse true NameNotDisplayedTrue".getBytes());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String str = sc.hasNext() ? sc.next() : "";
    //input delimiter
    String sArray[] = str.split(" ");


    if (sArray.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
    int i = 1;
    while (i < sArray.length && !sArray[i-1].equals("false")) {
        //you can access name here
        System.out.println(sArray[i]);
        i+=2;
    }
```

output:

Name

Name

Name